# For for/forEach loop doesn't iterate over all items

Tags: java, loops, lambda, bolts-framework

I'm currently using the bolts framework with parallel tasks (Task.whenAll()), I'm adding all my tasks into a list. Firstly I need to loop through my names list, but it just stops iterating after the first iteration (in the loop [1]).
The tasks get executed, but only for the first item in the loop. After that it just stops. So it makes only one iteration.

This is an example for the arrayList lHoster: [Vivo, OpenLoad, Streamango, FlashX, OpenLoadHD, TheVideo]

```
public Task<HashMap<String, Object>> getEpisode(String series, int season, String episode) {
        TaskCompletionSource<HashMap<String, Object>> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
        getEpisodeInformation(series, season, episode).onSuccess(task -> {
            List<String> lHoster = (ArrayList<String>) task.getResult().get("hoster");
            List<Task<?>> tHoster = new ArrayList<>();
            // Loop [1]. It only iterates through the first item, then just continues without any reason. Although there are normally 8 items in the string list
            lHoster.forEach(host -> tHoster.add(getOutLink(series, season, episode, host)));
            Task.whenAll(tHoster).onSuccess(task1 -> {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> hoster = new ArrayList<>();
                int i = 0;
                for (Task t : tHoster) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hostData = new HashMap<>();
                    hostData.put("out", (String) t.getResult());
                    hostData.put("name", ((ArrayList<String>) task.getResult().get("hoster")).get(i));
                    i++;
                }
                task.getResult().put("hoster", hoster);
                completion.setResult(task.getResult());
                return null;
            });
            return null;
        });
        return completion.getTask();
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that after the `lHoster.forEach(...)` statement, `lHoster.size()` and `tHoster.size()` are not the same?

Comment: No, lHoster just stores a list of strings, e.g. [a, b, c, d]. I iterate over the list, so obviously it should iterate through every item. But it doesn't, it just stops after the first iteration.

Comment: Unclear what iteration you're referring to. Are you saying that `lHoster.forEach(...)` only iterates once, i.e. only one element is added to `tHoster`, as I just asked? Because that's the iteration your `Loop [1]` comment is at. --- Or are you referring to the `for (Task t : tHoster)` loop only iterating once? Because that's far from your `Loop [1]` comment. --- I don't see any other iterations in your code.

Comment: @Andreas Exactly, it somehow just iterates once(+ all tasks for this iteration get triggered)

Comment: Ehhh WHAT???? What "iterates" once? The `lHoster.forEach()`, leaving `tHoster.size()` at 1, or what? You keep contracting yourself, and still haven't explicitly said ***WHAT*** code is iterating once. As far as I can tell, there is only two pieces of code that *should* iterate, aka run more than once: The code inside `forEach(...)` and the code inside `for (Task t : tHoster) { ... }`. Which of these are you referring to, or is there some other code that you believe should run more than once?